# HTML5 shiv are also needed for IE9 in order to support HTML5 elements

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5shiv

I use the following HTML5 elements in my pages: header, article, section and nav. 
Now I've set all the above HTML5 elements as display: block, and I include the HTML5 shiv with a conditional statement in the header:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The site works fine in IE7 & IE8 - indicating that html5shiv is indeed doing it's magic.
However when I test the site in IE9 it lacks styling for all the content inside HTML5 elements.

As soon as I change the conditional statement to:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The html5 elements and it's children now get the correct styling applied. I doublechecked my IE version and it says I have IE version 9.0.8112.16421.

I should also mention that the sites are built with PHP and cached through the use of PEAR's Cache_Lite. However tests done on a simple static html page give the same results for me.

Any ideas??

Comment: what is the `doctype` of your html file? do you use  `X-UA-COMPATIBLE`? btw. i think in the second example you mean `<!--[if lte IE 9]>`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> as reccomended by HTML5. Beneath the head element I use <meta charset="utf-8">. Thanks for noticing that, I updated my question - I use [if IE]

Comment: and you are sure that you dont use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` or send a header with `X-UA-Compatible:` ? (  http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-shim-ie-emulation-mode/ )

Comment: ...and you haven't set your IE to IE7/8 compatibility mode?

Comment: That's correct, I haven't set it to comp. mode. If I however set it to compability mode, and refresh the page - it will render just fine. (as expected because of the HTML5 shiv).

Comment: No headers are sent with X-UA-Compatible, same for the meta tag.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out what the problem was.
I had a comment at the top of my site, before the doctype html tag. That seems to break IE9's ability to recognize the HTML5 elements.

This is what I had:

```
<!-- Served From Cache: Wednesday 13th of February 2013 03:02:22 PM -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
```

So I was then able to fix this by moving the comment down beneath the doctype.

Comment: + 1 for coming back here and letting the community know. You might want to mark this as the correct answer too. As a general rule, nothing should ever become before the Doctype, because, as you have noticed, weird things start to happen!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>  
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>  
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: How does this help with the IE9 problem?

Comment: Did you read the question? He's already using a shiv. *"As soon as I change the conditional statement to: ... The html5 elements and it's children now get the correct styling applied."* The OP wants to know why IE9 doesn't style the elements *without* a shiv, since IE9 should support HTML5 elements natively. In any case, writing `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` will not do anything in IE9.

Comment: The html5shiv code is no longer hosted on `googlecode`. It has moved to [Github](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/tree/master/dist).